# Flink : Memory ran out exception

Tags: apache-flink, gelly

I set up a Flink cluster with the following configuration:

[image: Job Manager]
**The number of task managers: 2**
[image: Task Manager]

When I run the Connected Components algorithm (`org.apache.flink.graph.library.ConnectedComponents`) on a graph with 4 million edges and 1,750,000 vertices with parallelism 2, I get  this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error obtaining the sorted input: Thread 'SortMerger Reading Thread' terminated due to an exception: The record exceeds the maximum size of a sort buffer (current maximum: 87949312 bytes).
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.sort.UnilateralSortMerger.getIterator(UnilateralSortMerger.java:619)
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.getInput(BatchTask.java:1108)
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.NoOpDriver.run(NoOpDriver.java:82)
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:503)
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:368)
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:703)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Thread 'SortMerger Reading Thread' terminated due to an exception: The record exceeds the maximum size of a sort buffer (current maximum: 87949312 bytes).
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.sort.UnilateralSortMerger$ThreadBase.run(UnilateralSortMerger.java:800)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: The record exceeds the maximum size of a sort buffer (current maximum: 87949312 bytes).
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.sort.UnilateralSortMerger$ReadingThread.go(UnilateralSortMerger.java:955)
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.sort.UnilateralSortMerger$ThreadBase.run(UnilateralSortMerger.java:796)

According to my configuration, I do not know why it says `The record exceeds the maximum size of a sort buffer (current maximum:87949312 bytes)` while there is enough memory segments.

Is there anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems flink Gelly is not yet a popular package for calculating Graphs. I ran into the same problem.